# Como criar uma página de cadastro usando JSF + Spring

Tags: jsf, java-ee, spring-security

Estou criando uma página de cadastro de usuários mas estou encontrando o seguinte erro:

> type Exception report
>
> message Não é possível criar instância para·a classe:
>   managedBean.CadastroBean.
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: Não é possível criar instância para·a
>   classe: managedBean.CadastroBean.
>     javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
>   root cause
>
> com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Não é possível
>   criar instância para·a classe: managedBean.CadastroBean.
>     com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:191)
>     com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:100)
>     com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
>     com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
>     com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:257)
>     com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:117)
>     com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
>     com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
>     org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:80)
>     org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:135)
>     org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
>     com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
>     javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
>     javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
>     javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:174)
>     javax.faces.component.UIInput.getValue(UIInput.java:291)
>     org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.getValueToRender(ComponentUtils.java:77)
>     org.primefaces.component.inputmask.InputMaskRenderer.encodeMarkup(InputMaskRenderer.java:99)
>     org.primefaces.component.inputmask.InputMaskRenderer.encodeEnd(InputMaskRenderer.java:57)
>     javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
>     com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:312)
>     com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
>     com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
>     javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
>     javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
>     javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
>     javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
>     javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
>     javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
>     javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
>     javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
>     com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456)
>     com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
>     com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
>     com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>     com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
>     javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
>   root cause
>
> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to
>   org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User
>     managedBean.UsuarioFace.getUsu(UsuarioFace.java:45)
>     managedBean.UsuarioFace.(UsuarioFace.java:34)
>     managedBean.CadastroBean.(CadastroBean.java:31)
>     sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:186)
>     com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:100)
>     com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
>     com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
>     com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:257)
>     com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:117)
>     com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
>     com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
>     org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:80)
>     org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:135)
>     org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
>     com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
>     javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
>     javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
>     javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:174)
>     javax.faces.component.UIInput.getValue(UIInput.java:291)
>     org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.getValueToRender(ComponentUtils.java:77)
>     org.primefaces.component.inputmask.InputMaskRenderer.encodeMarkup(InputMaskRenderer.java:99)
>     org.primefaces.component.inputmask.InputMaskRenderer.encodeEnd(InputMaskRenderer.java:57)
>     javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
>     com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:312)
>     com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
>     com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
>     javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
>     javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
>     javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
>     javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:889)
>     javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
>     javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
>     javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
>     javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
>     com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456)
>     com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133)
>     com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
>     com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>     com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
>     javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)

Descrevendo melhor: Minha aplicação já utiliza o Spring Framework e funciona normalmente, mas agora eu preciso criar uma página para que qualquer pessoa se cadastre. Então na configuração do Spring já coloquei a página como `permitAll` .

Mas acontece que quando eu acesso a página ele me retorna o erro descrito. Mas quando eu logo em um usuário qualquer já cadastrado, e tento acessar a página, o acesso ocorre normalmente.

Meus códigos são o seguinte:

**cadastroUsuario.xhtml**

```
<h:body>
    <h:form id="formCadastroUsuario">
        <h:panelGrid id="panelUsuario" columns="2"
            style="margin-bottom:10px">

            <p:outputLabel for="cpf" value="CPF" />
            <p:inputMask id="cpf" value="#{cadastroBean.cpf}" mask="999.999.999-99" required="true" requiredMessage="Entre com um cpf"/>

            <h:outputLabel for="nascimento" value="Data Nascimento: " />
                            <p:calendar id="nascimento" value="#{cadastroBean.dataNascimento}" required="true" requiredMessage="Informe uma data." />

            <h:outputLabel for="pass" value="Senha" />
            <p:password id="pass" value="#{cadastroBean.novoUsuario.password}" redisplay="false" required="true"></p:password>

            <p:commandButton action="#{cadastroBean.inserirProprioUsuario}" value="Adicionar Usuário" ajax="false"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

**cadastroBean.java** (todos os getters e setters estão criados)

```
@ManagedBean(name="cadastroBean")
@SessionScoped
public class CadastroBean {

  private UsuarioDAO usuDAO = new UsuarioDAO();
  private Usuario usu;
  private Usuario novoUsuario = new Usuario();
  private String cpf;
  private Date dataNascimento;
  List<Usuario> listaUsuario = null;

  public String inserirProprioUsuario(){

    AlunoDAO alunoDAO = new AlunoDAO();
    System.out.println(cpf);
    System.out.println(dataNascimento);
    Aluno a = alunoDAO.buscaAlunoPorCpf(cpf);

    if (a != null){

        if(a.getDataNascimento().equals(getDataNascimento())) {

            if (usuDAO.getUsuarioPorMatricula(a.getMatricula()) == null){
                System.out.println("Não existe login com esse aluno");

                novoUsuario.setAluno(a);
                novoUsuario.setPassword(criptografarSenha(novoUsuario.getPassword()));


                usuDAO.inserirUsuario(novoUsuario);

                FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,"Sucesso","Cadastro com sucesso: "+novoUsuario.getUsername());  
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);

                listaUsuario = null;
                novoUsuario = new Usuario();
            }else{
                FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,"Aviso","Já existe um login cadastrado com essa matrícula.");  
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
            }
        }else{
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,"Aviso","Não existe aluno cadastrado com esse CPF.");  
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        }
    }
    return "usuarios";
  }
```

**security-app-context.xml**

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">
<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"
    jsr250-annotations="enabled" />
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true"
    access-denied-page="/negado.jsf">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login.jsf" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/cadastroUsuario.jsf" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/listaEditaisDisciplinas.jsf" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/realizarInscricoes.jsf" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <form-login login-page="/login.jsf" default-target-url="/realizarInscricoes.jsf"
        authentication-failure-url="/login.jsf" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/realizarInscricoes.jsf" />
</http>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider>
        <password-encoder hash="sha-256"></password-encoder>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
            authorities-by-username-query="select username, tipoUsuario from usuario where username=?"
            users-by-username-query="SELECT username, password, ativo  FROM usuario WHERE username=?" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <beans:property name="url"
        value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/monitoria" />
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="root" />
</beans:bean>
```

Como resolver?

Comment: Estranho, pode mostrar um pouco mais da stack de erro?

Comment: Vou colocar o resto @falsarella

Comment: @falsarella a internet caiu na hora que fui postar. Coloquei todo o stack.

Comment: O que eu não entendo, é que eu não uso o UsuarioFace em nenhum local, e ele dá erro nele.

Comment: Parece que você tem algum filtro configurado. Lá que o UsuarioFace é usado.

Answer (score 1):

Salve!

Eu ainda não tenho reputação para fazer comentários, então vou tentar responder a sua pergunta baseado no que você postou.

Parece que o problema é no acesso ao `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User`, que é o usuário autenticado.

> **java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User** managedBean.UsuarioFace.getUsu(UsuarioFace.java:45) managedBean.UsuarioFace.(UsuarioFace.java:34) managedBean.CadastroBean.(CadastroBean.java:31)

Funciona com usuários autenticados porque há uma referência válida de `User` no contexto. Como é um anônimo, é possível que essa referência ainda não exista. Você poderia postar a linha 45 da classe `UsuarioFace.java`? Daí eu posso ver como ocorre esse acesso/conversão.

Para acessar o usuário autenticado via contexto do Spring Security, normalmente eu faço algo similar à isso:

```
// AuthUtils
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
(...)

public static Authentication getAuthenticationObject() {

    if ((SecurityContextHolder.getContext() == null)) {
        return null;
    }

    final Authentication authentication = 
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

    if (authentication == null || authentication.getPrincipal() == null) {
        return null;
    }

    return authentication;

}

// recuperação do usuário autenticado
public static ApostadorUserDetails apostadorAutenticado() {
    final Authentication auth = AuthUtils.getAuthenticationObject();

    if(auth != null && auth.getPrincipal() instanceof ApostadorUserDetails) {
        return (ApostadorUserDetails) auth.getPrincipal();
    } else {
        return ApostadorUserDetails.apostadorAnonimo((AnonymousAuthenticationToken) auth);
    }
}
```

`ApostadorUserDetails` é uma referência do meu domínio que implementa `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails`. O método estático `apostadorAnonimo` é uma implementação do [Null Object Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern). Dessa forma não ocorre NPE ou erros de conversão.

Veja se ajuda ou deixe um comentário com mais informações que eu edito a minha resposta.